# Error al intentar crear un buscador en una tabla

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

Estoy tratando de reemplazar *JQuery* de mi aplicación hecha en *DJango*, y estoy probando con stimulus js, porque parece una buena opción junto con turbo, pero tengo un problema y es que al momento de ingresar el campo de búsqueda en el input y compararlo con lo que tengo en la tabla no me retorna los valores hasta que escribo el texto completo, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que me traiga los datos que se asimilan solo con escribir una letra y no la palabra completa:

```
<div data-controller="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." maxlength="15" data-action="search#searchTable"
        data-search-target="q">
    <table class="highlight centered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tipe de Tarea</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Fecha de Creacion</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for field in object_list %}
                <td data-search-target="name">{{ field.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ field.status|yesno:"Visible, No visible" }}</td>
                <td>{{ field.created_at }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#!">editar</a>
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
const application = Stimulus.Application.start();
const { Controller } = Stimulus;

application.register(
  'search',
  class extends Controller {
    static get targets() {
      return ['q', 'name'];
    }

    searchTable() {
      this.nameTargets.map((item) => {
        if (this.qTarget.value === item.textContent) {
          console.log('datos...');
        }
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que con `if (this.qTarget.value === item.textContent)` estás comparando la cadena completa. Puedes usar [`str.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) para verificar que la cadena contiene el valor buscado:

```
if (item.textContent.includes(this.qTarget.value))
```

Si quieres que la búsqueda sea insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, puedes convertir ambos valores a [minúsculas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```
if (item.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(this.qTarget.value.toLowerCase()))
```

`includes()` va a buscar coincidencias independientemente de la posición por lo que:

```
"cosmos multi".includes("mos") // Devuelve verdadero
```

Si necesitas que el valor a buscar sea desde el inicio de la cadena, entonces debes usar [`str.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
// Crear nuevas variables para no hacer líneas tan largas
let buscar = this.qTarget.value.toLowerCase();
let contenido = item.textContent.toLowerCase();
// Comparar desde la primera letra hasta la longitud del texto a buscar
if(contenido.substr(0, buscar.length) == buscar)
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ha sido de gran ayuda